# Every compact with the diameter $d$ in $C[0, 1]$ lies in a ball with the radius $d/2$.

Tags: calculus, general-topology, functional-analysis

Prove that all compacts with the diameter $d$ in the space $C[0, 1]$ of continous function on $[0,1]$ with $\sup$ norm lies in some closed ball with the radius $\frac{d}{2}$.

I found this problem in the student [book](https://libgen.is/book/index.php?md5=0D3057BEC3548A8D76EDBD341C562A85/) (Real and functional analysis. Bogachev V.I., Smolyanov O.G.), Chapter 1, problem 1.9.57., and can't solve it. Could you, please, help me.

Comment: Also in the student book noted that the problem is due to Erokhin.

Comment: I'll try and rephrase what I think is the question : So $C[0,1]$ is a normed linear space with the sup norm, hence it's a metric space as well. The question is : if $K \subset C[0,1]$ is a compact set such that for every $f,g \in K$, $\|f-g\|_{\sup} \leq d$ (i.e. that it has diameter $d$), then there is a $h \in C[0,1]$ such that for every $u \in K, \|u-h\|_{\sup} \leq \frac{d}{2}$, right? (That is, $K$ is contains in the ball of radius $\frac{d}{2}$ around $h$ for some "center point" $h \in C[0,1]$).

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Comment: Great. Can you provide the exact question number in the book of Smolyanov/Bogachev? I will find it , read it carefully and see if I can answer it using tools from that section itself. This reminds me of Jung's theorem (covering a compact set of certain diameter by a ball of a particular radius depending on that diameter). Please edit your question itself (i.e. no need to comment it, directly edit the question) with the appropriate question number.

Comment: Yes, of course! By the way, this book has an English edition too. :) Chapter 1, problem 1.9.57. [Book](https://libgen.is/book/index.php?md5=0D3057BEC3548A8D76EDBD341C562A85/): Real and functional analysis, Bogachev V.I., Smolyanov O.G. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Please edit the above comment into your question : it counts as context. I think this is a really nice problem, but I'll need to think about a solution for some time. Seen it, +1

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

You can try to look at the image of the evaluation map

$$e_t \colon K \to \mathbb{R}$$
that maps a function $f$ to $f(t)$. Clearly $e_t(K)$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ of diameter $\le 1$. Now show that $e_t(K)$ varies continuously with $t$. It will follow that the centroid of $K$  is also a continuous function of $t$. Use Arzela Ascoli ( converse) to get continuity.